# Overlapping polygons of different colors

Tags: google-maps, colors, polygon, opacity, overlap

Is it possible to prevent overlapping polygons from being darker at their intersection?

[image]

[Geocode's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46734157/171846) to drawing overlapping polygons at the same opacity works well for polygons of the same color, but not when there are multiple polygons.

I've tried to wind the polygons in [opposite directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole) but it had no effect. I also tried adjusting the polygon's [zIndex](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#PolygonOptions), but that only really affected which color was dominant in the intersection.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lrwyu63/5/) with my attempt at winding in opposite directions.

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

      html,
      body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // This example creates circles on the map, representing populations in North
      // America.

      // First, create an object containing LatLng and population for each city.
      var pointList = [{
        center: {
          lat: 40.514,
          lng: -74.205
        },
        population: 2714856,
        color: 'red'
      }, {
        center: {
          lat: 40.714,
          lng: -78.005
        },
        population: 8405837,
        color: 'blue'
      }, {
        center: {
          lat: 34.052,
          lng: -118.243
        },
        population: 3857799,
        color: 'yellow'
      }, ];

      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {
            lat: 40.714,
            lng: -78.005
          },
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var uniqueColours = [...new Set(pointList.map(point => point.color))];

        var direction = 1;
        uniqueColours.forEach(c => {
          var paths = [];

          if (direction == 1) direction = -1;
          else direction = 1;

          var pointsForColour = pointList.filter(p => p.color == c);

          pointsForColour.forEach(p => paths.push(drawCircle(p.center, Math.sqrt(p.population) * 100, direction)));

          // Add the circle for this city to the map.
          var cityCircle = new google.maps.Polygon({
            strokeColor: c,
            strokeOpacity: 0.5,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            fillColor: c,
            fillOpacity: 0.5,
            map: map,
            paths: paths,
            //center: citymap[city].center,
            //radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].population) * 100
          });
        });
      }

      function drawCircle(point, radius, dir) {
        var d2r = Math.PI / 180; // degrees to radians 
        var r2d = 180 / Math.PI; // radians to degrees 
        var earthsradius = 6378137.0; // 6378137.0 is the radius of the earth in meters
        var points = 32;
        if (typeof point.lat != "function") {
          if (typeof point.lat != "number") {
            alert("drawCircle: point.lat not function or number");
            return;
          }
          point = new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat, point.lng);
        }

        // find the raidus in lat/lon 
        var rlat = (radius / earthsradius) * r2d;
        var rlng = rlat / Math.cos(point.lat() * d2r);

        var extp = new Array();
        if (dir == 1) {
          var start = 0;
          var end = points + 1
        } // one extra here makes sure we connect the ends
        else {
          var start = points + 1;
          var end = 0
        }
        for (var i = start;
          (dir == 1 ? i < end : i > end); i = i + dir) {
          var theta = Math.PI * (i / (points / 2));
          ey = point.lng() + (rlng * Math.cos(theta)); // center a + radius x * cos(theta) 
          ex = point.lat() + (rlat * Math.sin(theta)); // center b + radius y * sin(theta) 
          extp.push(new google.maps.LatLng(ex, ey));
        }
        return extp;
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=&callback=initMap">


    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What color do you want the intersection to be? You probably will have to create code to do that, it won't do it "automatically" with different polygons (which they need to be to be different colors)

Comment: Thanks geocode. I'm aiming for the intersection to be either red or blue, depending on what order they are drawn in. It does sound like it'll have to be done in code.

Answer (score -1):

In the end I used square tiles that didn't overlap.